# Angular not rendering templates what is main and common

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to get some angular code to work and it seems that i am not quite understanding some of the syntax.

```
var mainModule = angular.module('main', ['common']);
```

1. What is the importance of "main"  is that specific to something?
2. What is "common"?

I DO reference the angular latest js and app.js in  layout.cshtml
I do not get any errors in chrome console.
My index.cshtml looks like

```
<div data-ng-controller="indexViewModel">

    <h1>{{ topic }}</h1>
```

here is my app.js

```
var mainModule = angular.module('main', ['common']);


mainModule.controller("indexViewModel", function (
$scope, $http, $q, $routeParams, $window, $location, viewModelHelper) {

var self = this;

$scope.topic = "Tasks";
$scope.author = "Tom";

console.log("test");

});

(function (myApp) {

var viewModelHelper = function (
  $http, $q, $window, $location) {

    var self = this;



    return this;
};


myApp.viewModelHelper = viewModelHelper;
}(window.MyApp));
```

**Update:**

Yes,  my body tag was missing ng-app

```
    <body data-ng-app="main">
```

Now i get the error with angular 1.5.6

angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module main due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module common due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'common' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

**Update 2:**

OK , i see  I NEEDED to have common defined since i called it that:

```
var commonModule = angular.module('common', ['ngRoute']);
var mainModule = angular.module('main', ['common']);
```

HOWEVER, getting this error now

`angular.js:13642 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: viewModelHelperProvider <- viewModelHelper <- indexViewModel
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/unpr?p0=viewModelHelperProvider%20%3C-%20viewModelHelper%20%3C-%20indexViewModel
    at angular.js:68`

**Update 3   FIXED**

I needed to add in this factory code

```
commonModule.factory('viewModelHelper',
    function ($http, $q, $window, $location) {
        return MyApp.viewModelHelper(
            $http, $q, $window, $location);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ng-app` directive tells `AngularJS` that this is the root element of the AngularJS application.

You can only have one `ng-app` directive in your HTML document. If more than one `ng-app` directive appears, the first appearance will be used.

So, in `angular.module('main', ['common'])`, `main` is the value of `ng-app` directive and `common` is the dependency on which your module `main` depends.

Take an example of routing, we inject the dependency `ngRoute` in the angular.module for routing of application.

**Syntax :** angular.module('main', ['ngRoute'])

Here, `main` is depends on `ngRoute` because without `ngRoute` module angular can not perform routing.

Comment: Sorry for the delay :   yes  ng-app i had forgotten!   But with this angular 1.5.6   is common still correct?

Comment: angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module main due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module common due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'common' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Answer (score 0):

1. `angular.module('main', ['common'])` - `main` is the name of your module - you will later use it in HTML as the value of `ng-app`, and `['common']` is another module that your module depends on.
2. Make sure you defined `ng-app="main"` in your html. this is the first thing you need to define before you declare any controller
3. make sure you include angular.js as a script in your html (`<script src="path/to/angular.js"></script>`)?

Comment: Hey,  OP and you I meant to get back to earlier...   Yes  ng-app was missing,   but with angular 1.5.6  is it possible that "common" is not correct?

Comment: angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module main due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module common due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'common' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the angular version, it just means that the common module is not defined. There are 2 possible reasons: 1. You didn't define a common module anywhere (angular.module('common', [])), 2. You defined a common module but didn't include the script file in your html